# Tradingview client sending Json structure as plain text/data

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful, tradingview-api

I am trying to send JSON formatted data to a Python / Flask server.

According to this documentation:
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=OANDA%3ANAS100USD&solution=43000529348

> If the alert message is valid JSON, we will send a request with an
> "application/json" content-type header. Otherwise, we will send
> "text/plain" as a content-type header.

The only thing is, what I get seems to be dependent upon whether or not the variables work. For example:

```
This works:
{
    "tradeid": "5L5A0",
    "message": "",
    "accountid": 20,
    "ticker": 20,
    "currentprice": 21,
    "action": "X_OPEN"
}
```

It has a content type of **"application/json"**
I would say that because on the server side:

```
test = request.get_json()
```

works fine

but when I use

`ticker: {{close}}` in place of `ticker: 20`, then then it does the replacement - but - the content-type must be getting set to `"text/plain"`. I only say that because in that case, only request.data will get an unstructured version of the data. In that case,

```
request.data
```

returns the data (totally **ignoring any JSON structuring**)

How does one fix this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem JSON formatted messages in TradingView alerts are being sent as plain text. Here is my message:

```js
{
  "side": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
  "symbol": "{{ticker}}",
  "type": "{{orderType}}",
  "position": "{{positionDirection}}",
  "size": "{{size}}",
  "funds": "{{funds}}",
  "marginMode": "{{marginMode}}",
  "autoBorrow": "{{autoBorrow}}",
  "orderMode": "{{orderMode}}"
}
```

Help

Comment: If you have same issue, please comment or better just give the question a upvote. If you have related question kindly make another post instead of writing in the answer section. Enjoy SO

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34417686)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I've come across a similar issue before. If I recall correctly, there were instances when TradingView sent data in text/plain format even when it seemed to contain valid JSON, depending on the message format.

As it's something I couldn't change, my approach was to use force=True while obtaining JSON data from the request, and then examining the JSON properties.

Here's the code I used:

```
json_data = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)
```

Adding silent=True also helped by preventing get_json from throwing an error when the data wasn't valid JSON, instead returning None.