# converting Flask message received in in "text/plain" format to JSON format

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I have an issue with FLASK that I am hoping to resolve.

I am sending this type of input to a Flask server:

```
[
    "tradeid": "5L5A0",
    "message": "",
    "accountid": 20,
    "ticker": {{ticker}},
    "currentprice": {{close}},
    "action": "X_OPEN"
]
```

I have also tried (changing `]` to `}` ):

```
{
    "tradeid": "5L5A0",
    "message": "",
    "accountid": 20,
    "ticker": {{ticker}},
    "currentprice": {{close}},
    "action": "X_OPEN"
}
```

The server does change {{ticker}} and {{close}} values so that they are "filled" with actual data ( as seen here in the debugger):

(Pdb) p request.data
**b'[\n    "tradeid": "5L5A0",\n    "message": "",\n    "accountid": 20,\n    "ticker": BTCUSDT,\n    "currentprice": 19091.4,\n    "action": "X_OPEN"\n]'**

```
The snippet of code looks like this:
671     @tview_api.route('/record_alerts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
672     def save_tview_alerts( ):
673         try:
674             breakpoint()
675             #req_data = request.get_json()
676  ->         req_data = request.data
```

**The problem is** that it is sending it as plain text and not json  (otherwise **request.get_json()** would work).

How can I convert this result to JSON format?

Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated

TIA

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to all who have responded. I have been asked if I could send the data as : **"application/json"**  I am using a Webhook from Tradingview. They have informed me that "they are working on it" - but - in the meantime, I was trying to find a workaround.

Again, any help, hints or advice would be appreciated

Background message is here: [Tradingview client sending Json structure as plain text/data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74040019/tradingview-client-sending-json-structure-as-plain-text-data)

Comment: Can't you just set `force=True` (`request.get_json(force=True)`)?

Comment: Are you sending the request with a Content-Type header whose value is "application/json"?

Comment: @larsks - i have tried this with no success

Comment: What happens when you try? Is it possible you're not sending a valid JSON document? Can you print out (and include in your question) the content of `request.data`?

Comment: @Detlef - have updated message with background info

Comment: @larsks - this is what I am getting when printing the information in request.data: 
b'[\n    "tradeid": "5L5A0",\n    "message": "",\n    "accountid": 20,\n    "ticker": BTCUSDT,\n    "currentprice": 19091.4,\n    "action": "X_OPEN"\n]'

Comment: @larsks "That's not valid JSON syntax:" - This is the background on the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74040019/tradingview-client-sending-json-structure-as-plain-text-data        (just looking for a work-a-round now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, this isn't valid JSON syntax:

```
[
 "tradeid": "5L5A0",
 "message": "",
 "accountid": 20,
 "ticker": BTCUSDT,
 "currentprice": 19091.4,
 "action": "X_OPEN"
]
```

The `[...]` delimiters are for specifying a *list*, something like:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

If you want `key: value` items, you need a dictionary (called an "object" in JSON parlance):

```
{
 "tradeid": "5L5A0",
 "message": "",
 "accountid": 20,
 "ticker": BTCUSDT,
 "currentprice": 19091.4,
 "action": "X_OPEN"
}
```

Except that's *still* not valid syntax, because `BTCUSDT` isn't a valid JSON value: it's neither a string, nor a number, nor a boolean value, nor null. You need to fix that:

```
{
  "tradeid": "5L5A0",
  "message": "",
  "accountid": 20,
  "ticker": "BTCUSDT",
  "currentprice": 19091.4,
  "action": "X_OPEN"
}
```

Using the above data and this code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

tview_api = Flask(__name__)


@tview_api.route("/record_alerts", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def save_tview_alerts():
    req_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    return req_data
```

I can POST the above data without errors.

You need to update your template to look like:

```
{
    "tradeid": "5L5A0",
    "message": "",
    "accountid": 20,
    "ticker": "{{ticker}}",
    "currentprice": {{close}},
    "action": "X_OPEN"
}
```

Because I'm using `request.get_json(force=True)` in the above code, we don't care about the `Content-type` header of the request. If you can ensure you're using the appropriate `Content-type` header (`application/json`), then you could simply reference the `request.json` attribute.

If you are unsure about JSON syntax, you can utilize a JSON validator like [this one](https://jsonlint.com/) to check your data. For example, attempting to validat
e your dictionary with the unquoted string, that site tells us:

```
Error: Parse error on line 5:
...id": 20, "ticker": BTCUSDT,  "currentpr
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: I used https://jsonlint.com/ to verify a good JSON format and came up with : 
[{
 "tradeid": "5L5A0",
 "message": "",
 "accountid": 20,
 "ticker": "{{ticker}}",
 "currentprice": {{close}},
 "action": "X_OPEN"
}]

When using "force=True" it all worked

Thanks again

Comment: This is what worked when sending it from Tradingview